# Pandas Code script for the function mean() in DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, mean

Where can I get the code script in the backend of pandas for the function DataFrame.mean()??

Answer (score 0):

Here. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.4.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L11101-L11119

Any method you are looking for, you can go to the docs website (for example [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html)) and then click on the [source] button.